How should a dual citizen answer the nationality questions on the ESTA application form?
I'm currently applying for my ESTA and have run into some issues regarding these two questions:

Are you now a citizen or national of any other country?

Have you ever been a citizen or national of any other country?


I have dual citizenship (country A is the only I have a passport from, it's also the only one that's part of the Visa Waiver Program). Now, I have answered yes to the first question, but does that mean I should also answer yes to the second one? If yes, then what date do I enter? Just today's date?

Excluding the two citizenships you hold (and are declaring in Q1), what other citizenship(s) have you held?

I believe question two is asking about past citizenship - country that you were citizen of in the past but are no longer.  I don't have a source to back that up though, it's just how I read it.

Take a careful look at the ESTA form. Compare it to the CBP ESTA form quoted in @JonathanReez' Answer. Looks like there are actually Three questions, not two.

The full section reads as follows. Let's imagine you're applying as a dual Czech-German citizen, with the Czech passport being your primary.

Other Citizenship/Nationality

It's other citizenship so you don't include your Czech citizenship in the following questions.

Are you now, a citizen or national of any other country?

You would write "Germany" here because you've already included "Czech Republic" in the primary section of the application.

Have you ever been a citizen or national of any other country?

You wouldn't include any countries here because they're asking about other countries and you've already mentioned both Czech and German citizenships. If you were previously also a Polish citizen, you'd include that here. But you wouldn't write down any countries that are already mentioned above.

How do you determine which passport is the primary?

@NaveedAhmed its whatever passport you put into the first part of the application. If both passports are ESTA-eligible, pick the one from the country with a higher GDP/capita as your primary. If only one is eligible, pick that one.
